# Eclipse Android project Compile with 4.0.3 not loading

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

As the title says, I have a problem with Eclipse when trying to create an Android Project which Compiles with Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15).

I have installed all the needed packages with the SDK Manager.
So when I choose to compile with 4.0.3, my `MainActivity` is full of errors (`R cannot be resolved to a variable`, `activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field`, etc.).

The Graphical layout is not loaded as well.
Worth to mention that it all works fine with the 2.3.3 & 5.1.1 API Levels.
I tried to change and combine various cases of minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion, with or without theme, etc.

If anyone has an idea of what's wrong, I would appreciate your time and help.
I don't have enough reputation points to attach a photo showing the errors

Errors shown in console when I create Android App Project:

> Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time. Versions found are: Path: C:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar Length: 1074044 SHA-1: 33b27a8d2a5b87e6eb6c60e87a5374ffbfeacc3a Path: C:\AndroidProjects\TestProject\libs\android-support-v4.jar Length: 1157300 SHA-1: b1fe665b784aa7314d722b2ec17e77f83ba2e717 Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

And countless number of error lines this type:

> C:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, could you copy the error messages and paste them into your question? Use the code formatting button in the edit toolbar to make them look nice.

Comment: Add the error message, it will help others to help you.

Comment: Errors shown in console when I create Android App Project:
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

Versions found are:
Path: C:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
  Length: 1074044
  SHA-1: 33b27a8d2a5b87e6eb6c60e87a5374ffbfeacc3a

 Path: C:\AndroidProjects\TestProject\libs\android-support-v4.jar
  Length: 1157300
  SHA-1: b1fe665b784aa7314d722b2ec17e77f83ba2e717

 Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: And countless number of error lines this type: 
C:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

Comment: Add the errors as part of your question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not build properly.

do Clean your project once. Try to run the project.

If

```
import android.R;
```

line is there in your project, please remove this line and include

```
import com.yourpackage.yourclassname.R;
```

Again clean and run your project. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

remove any imports such as

```
import android.support.v7.appcompat;
```

This is library project, Eclipse might sometimes automatically import this coz of some unknown reasons like yours. And also if u see that ur class extending ActionBar Activity replace it by only activity. And do as said by the user above (Harish).
Also try cleaning, restarting the eclipse.
If all this fails, then download the new SDK.